# Javascript referrer check based on the domain

Tags: javascript, referrer

I need JS on a page to check if the referrer - the previous page - comes from the same domain.

The URL of a page with the JS is formatted like this:

http://subdomain.site.com/dir/page?vs=123456

There could be multiple previous pages. So, the JS needs to check that the domains match.

If the domain is different I want to sent the user to another page.

This is what I tried to get working:

```
var matchHost = /^https?:\/\/.*\//;
var match = matchHost.exec(document.referrer);
var domain = "http://subdomain.site.com/dir/";   

if (match !== domain) {
window.location.href = domain;
}
```

But doesn't quite work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never trust the referer. Can be easily spoofed and is often suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

You may don't need regex at all. You know your domain's characters length e.g with url http://example.com count the characters and then split the string according to the url domain length of the referral then cmopare it with your domain url! That' all.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `match` is an array of matched strings. So it will never be equal. You need to compare `match[0]`:

```
if (match.length== 0 || match[0]!== domain) ...
```

Or you can avoid regex at all by doing this:

```
if (document.referrer.substr (0, domain.length).toLowerCase()!== domain) ...
```